# All displays updating when radio is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a table displaying various inputs sums that a user has entered based upon which radio they have selected and what numbers they have entered into the fields. I am using table data cells to display the outputs and each is updating as it should when the user changes the data in the actual input fields. However, on check of the radio button, all cells are updating and I only want the once td cell updating at a time when the user checks a different box. Currently all cells are updating when any radio is clicked. Here is the nastiness:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//  var updateTotal, currentAPR;
var updateTotal, currentAPR = '7.95%';

$("body").on("blur", "#vehiclePrice,#estimatedTaxesAndFees,#downPayment,#manufacturerRebate,#tradeInValue,#amtOwedOnTrade,#extendedWarranty,#gapInsurance,#serviceContract", function () {
    updateTotal(currentAPR);
});
updateTotal = function (apr) {
    currentAPR = apr;
    $(".output2").html(apr);
    $(".output3").html(apr + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");

    var input1 = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0;
    var input2 = parseInt($('#estimatedTaxesAndFees').val()) || 0;
    var input3 = parseInt($('#downPayment').val()) || 0;
    var input4 = parseInt($('#manufacturerRebate').val()) || 0;
    var input5 = parseInt($('#tradeInValue').val()) || 0;
    var input6 = parseInt($('#amtOwedOnTrade').val()) || 0;
    var input7 = parseInt($('#extendedWarranty').val()) || 0;
    var input8 = parseInt($('#gapInsurance').val()) || 0;
    var input9 = parseInt($('#serviceContract').val()) || 0;
    var sum = input1 + input2 - input3 - input4 - input5 + input6 + input7 + input8 + input9;
    $('.total').text('$' + sum.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
    var principle = parseInt($('#vehiclePrice').val()) || 0;
    var apr = $("input[name='status']:checked").attr("apr");
    var months = $("input[name='status']:checked").attr("months");
    var perMonth = sum * (apr / 12) / (1 - Math.pow((1 + (apr / 12)), -months)).toFixed(2);
    var perMonth48 = sum * (0.0595 / 12) / (1 - Math.pow((1 + (0.0595 / 12)), -months)).toFixed(2);
    var perMonth60 = sum * (0.0695 / 12) / (1 - Math.pow((1 + (0.0695 / 12)), -months)).toFixed(2);
    var perMonth72 = sum * (0.0795 / 12) / (1 - Math.pow((1 + (0.0795 / 12)), -months)).toFixed(2);
    $('.perMonth').text('$' + perMonth.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
     $('.perMonth2').text('$' + perMonth.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
     $('.perMonth48').text('$' + perMonth48.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
     $('.perMonth60').text('$' + perMonth60.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));
     $('.perMonth72').text('$' + perMonth72.toFixed(0).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,'));


};
$('label.option').click(function () {
    $('.form-item input[type=radio]').attr('checked', null);
    $('label.option').removeClass("checked").addClass("unchecked");
    $(this).prev().attr('checked', "checked");
    $(this).addClass("checked").removeClass("unchecked");
});

$("input[name='status']").click(function () {
    console.log("changed");
    if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '36') {
        updateTotal("4.95%");
        //$(".output2").html("4.36%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
    } else if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '48') {
        updateTotal("5.95%");
        //$(".output2").html("4.74%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
    } else if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '60') {
        updateTotal("6.95%");
        //$(".output2").html("4.94%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
    } else if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '72') {
        updateTotal("7.95%");
        //$(".output2").html("5.30%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
    } else if ($("input[name='status']:checked").val() == '') {
        updateTotal("");
        //$(".output2").html("5.30%" + "<span class=\"expandedTermsText\"> APR<\/span>");
    }
});
});
```

Here is the HTML (I am not displaying the 36 mos for this form so not sure if that is affecting it too:

```
           <div id="edit-status" class="form-radios"> 
              <!--    <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-status">
               <input type="radio" id="edit-status-0" name="status" value="36" apr="0.0495" months="36" class="form-radio radioCursor"/>
                  <label class="option unchecked" for="edit-status-0">36 mos</label>
                </div> -->
              <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-status">
                <table class="gridStyleTable">
                  <tr>
                    <td>   <h2 class="termsGreenCustom perMonth48">$671<span class="expandedTermsText"> /mo</span></h2>
                      <input type="radio" id="edit-status-1" name="status" value="48" apr="0.0595" months="48" class="form-radio radioCursor"/>
                      <label class="option unchecked" for="edit-status-1">48 mos</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td> <h2 class="termsGreenCustom">5.95%<span class="expandedTermsText"> APR</span></h2>  </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>  48 mos</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-status label_main_selected'">
                <table class="gridStyleTable label_main_selected'">
                  <tr>
                    <td>  <h2 class="termsGreenCustom perMonth60">$568<span class="expandedTermsText"> /mo</span></h2>
                      <input type="radio" id="edit-status-2" name="status" value="60" apr="0.0695" months="60" class="form-radio radioCursor"/>
                      <label class="option unchecked" for="edit-status-2">60 mos</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><h2 class="termsGreenCustom">6.95%<span class="expandedTermsText"> APR</span></h2>  </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td> 60 mos </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
              <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-status">
                <table class="gridStyleTable">
                  <tr>
                    <td>  <h2 class="termsGreenCustom perMonth72">$469<span class="expandedTermsText"> /mo</span></h2>
                      <input type="radio" id="edit-status-3" name="status" value="72" apr="0.0795" months="72" checked="checked" class="form-radio radioCursor"/>
                      <label class="option checked" for="edit-status-3">72 mos</label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>   <h2 class="termsGreenCustom">7.95%<span class="expandedTermsText"> APR</span></h2></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td> 72 mos </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
```

Comment: how about a jsFiddle or a plunker?

Comment: working on it. I actually figured out why some of it was happening. Having these bound to the radios for this is causing then all to update:         updateTotal("6.95%");